# Understanding the Sequential Probability Ratio Test

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, sequential-analysis

I am trying to understand how to apply SPRT to the following case.

Random variable $X$ is exponentially distributed according to $f(x, \theta)$. Test the following hypotheses

$$
H_0 : \theta \ge \theta_0
$$

$$
H_1 : \theta < \theta_0
$$

However, ever example I have found of SPRT uses hypotheses for the form $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ and $H_1:\theta=\theta_1$ which leads to the use of the ratio of two probability density functions $f_0=f(x,\theta_0)$ and $f_1=f(x,\theta_1)$.

I cannot figure out how the hypotheses that I want to test can be applied to SPRT.

Comment: Welcome to CV, chuck1! This: $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ and $H_1:\theta=\theta_1$ appears to be a test formulated using the [Neyman-Pearson lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma) (NPL) which posits two competing statements ($H_0$ and $H_1$) and more or less asks "which of these do to data provide more supporting evidence for?" The NPL is a different approach to hypothesis testing than the kinds of frequentist tests more prevalent in modern introductory applied statistics textbooks (including the one-sided test of $H_0 : \theta \ge \theta_0$ vs $H_1 : \theta < \theta_0$).

Comment: @Alexis Thanks! Clearly I have a lot to learn and you have given me some more keywords to check out :)